# How to resolve NoMethodError in ror version 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I clicked on "display your data" link it is showing me the following error.

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
Showing C:/Site/new/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2bd81e8>
```

My code snippets are given below.

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Choose your option</h1>
<%= link_to "Enter your data",users_new_path %>
<%= link_to "Display your data",users_show_path %>
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Enter your data here</h1>
<%= form_for @user,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field:name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %><br>
    <%= f.email_field:email,placeholder:"Enter your email" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field:message,placeholder:"Enter your message"%><br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Display your data</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>
          <strong>Name:</strong>
          <%= @user.name %>
        </p>
       <p>
         <strong>Email:</strong>
         <%= @user.email %>
       </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Message:</strong>
          <%= @user.message %>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
<%= link_to "Edit",users_edit_path(:id => t.id) %><%= link_to "Delete",users_delete_path(:id => t.id),data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete it ?' }  %>
<%= link_to "Back",users_index_path %>
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(users_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice]="Your data is saved succesfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="You are entering wrong data"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
  def show
    @user=User.all
  end
  def delete
   @user=User.find(params[:id])
    @user.delete
  end
  def edit
    @edit=User.find(params[:id])
    @user=User.new
  end
  def update
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(update_params)
      flash[:notice]="Your data has updated successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="Your data could not update..check it.."
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :edit

    end
  end
  private
  def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :message,pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
  end
  def update_params
    params.require (:user).permit(:name,:email,:message,pets_attributes: [:name,:email,:message])
  end
end
```

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name,  :presence => true,:length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :message,  :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You should fix your `show` action from:

```
def show
  @user = User.all
end
```

to:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In `show` action, you have

```
@user = User.all
```

which assigns relation with all users to `@user` variable. That's why you have this error, because you can't query whole relation for `email`. You should have:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

`User.find(params[:id])` returns single `User` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
    @user=User.all
  end
```

This will return array of users instead of user, so in order to call email on it you have to iterate loop over it.

```
<% user in @users %> <!-- I have change @user to @users in show method -->
  <h1>Display your data</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>
          <strong>Name:</strong>
          <%= user.name %>
        </p>
       <p>
         <strong>Email:</strong>
         <%= user.email %>
       </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Message:</strong>
          <%= user.message %>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
<%= link_to "Edit",users_edit_path(:id => t.id) %><%= link_to "Delete",users_delete_path(:id => t.id),data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete it ?' }  %>
<%= link_to "Back",users_index_path %>
<% end %>
```

Or just change show method

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Don't you think that displaying all users should be performed in `index`?

Comment: Yes, I agree. but i just wanted to explain why it is throwing error  and how he can display in those cases. However i have editef the answer

Answer (score -1):

fix your show action.
replace 
`@user = User.all` 
with

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```